# Any clues or links to how to colorify c# files on Emacs (for windows) not cygwin?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, emacs

I have installed Emacs for windows and I am trying to use it to edit some c# files confortably, as usual, but cannot find ways to colorify it in c#, the information available only instructs to config it in Linux

any help will be apreciated, if not I will just rename the cs file to c and I supose that it will solve the problem

thanks in advance

ARsoftware

Comment: the information on https://code.google.com/archive/p/csharpmode/ is not working in Emacs 26 for windows...

Comment: It seems you are trying to make something work that has a dependency on a deprecated (or at least unloved) NRefactor!  - Perhaps try this? http://codinggorilla.com/?p=2352  Not sure if it fits your bill

Comment: I will check it in 10 hours, thanks, money is not problem for my family, at least here in Brazil

Comment: Ha -  the beauty of the ambiguity of the English language!  "If ti fits your bill" is a saying like "if it suits your situation" - I don't think what I suggested costs anything (but let me know).

Comment: I love Emacs and Linux but I was born as a Windows developer, but the majority of my code can easily ported to Cygwin or real Unix

Comment: The development in Emacs is powerful like Vscode but have not figured out how to enable advanced intelisense like Vscode, these days I am using Vscode for programming notepad++ as grep and find, but sometimes  powerful force forces me to use even Vim